# "Critical file transfer error" when downloading (pgp encrypted) files from an FTP server

Tags: encryption, ftp, pgp

I need to receive client data from a supplier via FTP. The way this process is supposed to work is that I connect to the supplier's network via VPN, then connect to the FTP server and download the PGP-encrypted files from the server.

I have managed to set up the VPN connection and I can connect to the FTP server using FileZilla. I see the files (XYZ.pgp) in the server's directory. However, whenever I try to download them, the FTP client returns the following error message:

> ```
> Response:       550 Failed to open file.   
> Error:               Critical file transfer error
> ```

I believe that I have the right permissions, as I'm able to move the encrypted files into a different directory, as well as create and upload files on the FTP server. I assume the problem is due to the encryption of the files, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It does not matter for the server if the file is encrypted. The server just transfers files and does not look at the content.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I noticed that my FTP client shows a different "Owner/Group" for the files that I cannot transfer - could that be the issue? What surprises me is that I can rename the files that I'm unable to transfer.

Comment: In UNIX the name of a file is a property of the directory (a file might have multiple names) and thus changing it requires the appropriate directory permissions. Reading the file instead depends on the permissions on the file (inode). It is likely that you don't have these permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of that. That seems to be consistent with what is going on otherwise. I will ask them to check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The commenter Steffen Ullrich was indeed correct. The encryption was not the problem, but rather that the permissions had been set incorrectly.

Comment: "**Response: 550 Failed to open file.**" from FTP says it all; well if it had added "Permission denied" , thenit would have been perfect.